# Settings transparency on bitmap before using STM_SETIMAGE

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

I have a static control that I am setting an image on by sending STM_IMAGE to the control with my bitmap. This works fine but I want the bitmap to have a transparent background. I have the following code:

```
case WM_PAINT:
{
    HBITMAP hbmBmp, hbmMask;
    BITMAP bm;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    HWND hCtrl = GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_BUTTONNEWGAME);
    hbmBmp = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_NEWGAMEBUTTONBITMAP));
    GetObject(hbmBmp, sizeof(BITMAP), &bm);
    hbmMask = CreateBitmapMask(hbmBmp, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    HDC hDCMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HDC hDCMem2 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HDC hdcResult = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

    SelectObject(hDCMem, hbmMask);
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hDCMem, 0, 0, SRCAND);

    SelectObject(hDCMem, hbmBmp);
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hDCMem, 0, 0, SRCPAINT);

    // At this point I can see the bitmap with a transparent background at (0,0)
    // The following code attempts to copy from hdc into a memory DCand to form a new bitmap 
    //that I use in the STM_SETIMAGE message

    HBITMAP newBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight); // create blank bitmap
    SelectObject(hdcResult, newBitmap); // store in memory DC
    BitBlt(hdcResult, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); // copy from hdc to memory DC

    // This line is just for checking that hdcResult contains the correct data
    // It copies back from the memory DC into hdc to the right of the original bitmap
    // I now see two bitmaps with transparent bitmaps next to each other as I expected
    BitBlt(hdc, bm.bmWidth, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcResult, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); 
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    // sending this does not set the bitmap on the static control
    // I do not see anything where the control should be
    SendMessage(hCtrl, STM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)newBitmap);
}
break;
```

The static control is created with SS_BITMAP style in the following code:

```
case WM_CREATE:
{
    HWND newGameText = CreateWindowW(
        L"STATIC",
        L"",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_BITMAP | SS_NOTIFY,  // Styles 
        150,         // x position 
        150,         // y position 
        74,        //  width
        24,        //  height
        hWnd,     // Parent window
        (HMENU)ID_BUTTONNEWGAME,
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
        NULL);      // Pointer not needed.
}
break;
```

Do I need to copy the bitmap to the specific position of the control (this seems unreasonable) in the device context or am I doing something completely impossible / stupid?

Comment: I'm aware I should also be deleting the device contexts after usage.

Comment: You aren't creating a bitmap with (alpha) transparency. The first two calls to `BitBlt` create the **illusion** of transparency, by only writing to pixels, that aren't masked. Once done, the pixels that haven't been changed still have their background color. If you want transparency, use [STM_SETIMAGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760782.aspx) with `IMAGE_ICON`. Icons support transparency (possibly even alpha transparency with the [introduction of PNG support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101022-00/?p=12473)).

Comment: Thanks but I am not seeing anything on the button, not even a bitmap without transparency. I will edit the OP to make this clearer.

Comment: Does your static control have the `SS_BITMAP` style? Incidentally, since it's ID is `ID_BUTTONNEWGAME`, is it really a static control? It's probably also a good idea to select the `newBitmap` out of the device context before passing it on. Otherwise it is owned by the device context. This will bite once you implement proper clean-up.

Comment: Yes the control is created with SS_BITMAP style. I will add the creation code to the OP.

Comment: Technically, you should be passing `NULL` for the *hInstance* parameter to `CreateWindow`, but that shouldn't make a difference ([What is the HINSTANCE passed to CreateWindow and RegisterClass used for?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050418-59/?p=35873)).

Comment: you should pass NULL to create memory DC and don't forget: FillRect() to clear memory bitmap you created "newBitmap"

Comment: I assume you put the code in the `WM_PAINT` handler for testing purposes. If that is the case, could you update your question and explicitly point out, that this is just for testing, and the final code will be placed in a `WM_INITDIALOG` handler? I keep losing my reputation, because I have to down vote on proposed answers that keep assuming, that you are actually trying to render the static control.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think making the control `SS_BITMAP` AND processing the `WM_PAINT` message makes sense. And sending an `STM_SETIMAGE` (ie changing the bitmap displayed) in response to every paint request (`WM_PAINT` message) is quite an overkill, isn't it? And after you are done, you should delete everything (the DCs & bitmaps you created AND the the value returned by the `STM_SETIMAGE` message (previous bitmap passed to the control).

Either make the control `SS_BITMAP` and use `STM_SETIMAGE` or make it owner-drawn and process the `WM_DRAWITEM` message.

You may also want to check the `TransparentBlt()` function.

---

I'm adding some code of a working example here. Simple and easy to implement, having to write very little code. The owner-drawn case indeed draws a bitmap with transparent areas. All is done using old-school GDI (not GDI+) functions.

In this example I create a dialog with three static controls, implemented in a different way:

- `IDC_IMG1` **:** `SS_BITMAP` style, with the image set in the resource file
- `IDC_IMG2` **:** `SS_BITMAP` style initially without an image, image set with the STM_SETIMAGE message
- `IDC_IMG3` **:** `SS_OWNERDRAW` style, dislpaying a bitmap with transparent areas

**Resource File Contents:**

```
IDB_BITMAP1    BITMAP    "Image1.bmp"
.
.
// Dialog Items
CONTROL    IDB_BITMAP1,IDC_IMG1,"Static",SS_BITMAP,7,7,136,126,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
CONTROL    "",IDC_IMG2,"Static",SS_BITMAP,154,7,17,15,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
CONTROL    "",IDC_IMG3,"Static",SS_OWNERDRAW,301,7,136,123,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
```

**Source Code:**

```
// Resources
HBITMAP hBitmap = NULL;
int bmpW, bmpH;

INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            if (!hBitmap) // Initialize resources if not initialized already
            {
                BITMAP bmp;
                hBitmap = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1));
                GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bmp), &bmp);
                bmpW = bmp.bmWidth;
                bmpH = bmp.bmHeight;
            }
            // Set bitmap in IDC_IMG2
            SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_IMG2, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap);
            break;
        case WM_DRAWITEM:
            if (wParam==IDC_IMG3) // Draw transparent bitmap in IDC_IMG3
            {
                LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDIS = (LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT)lParam;
                HDC hMem = CreateCompatibleDC(lpDIS->hDC);
                HGDIOBJ hOldBmp = SelectObject(hMem, hBitmap);
                TransparentBlt(lpDIS->hDC, 0, 0, bmpW, bmpH, hMem, 0, 0, bmpW, bmpH, RGB(255,255,255));
                SelectObject(hMem, hOldBmp);
                DeleteDC(hMem);
                return TRUE;
            }
            break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
                EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            break;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

And here is the result:
[image]

Comment: This doesn't address the issue. There is no problem at all with setting a static control's style to contain `SS_BITMAP` and handling `WM_PAINT` of it's **parent**. And `TransparentBlt` tries to solve a problem, that doesn't exist. Plus, that doesn't produce a transparent bitmap either.

Comment: Well, I disagree with everything you say here. Of course it's wrong to paint a SS_BITMAP static control, as these controls have an associated bitmap (either as defined in the resource file, or assigned one through the STM_SETIMAGE msg); they do paint themselves, so what's the point of painting them over? And should the image be CHANGED on each paint request (what STM_SETIMAGE actually does)? No, no no!!! And TransparentBlt() tries to solve a problem, that doesn't exist???  Of course it does exist, and that's exactly what the OP is after. Does it easily, with just one call too!

Comment: This is not about opinions. The purpose of the code in the question is to generate a bitmap on the fly, and set it as the static control's image. The `WM_PAINT` handler **does not** paint the static control (it's not created as an owner-drawn control). Setting the bitmap in the `WM_PAINT` handler is not ideal (`WM_INITDIALOG` would be more appropriate). But with proper resource management this need not be wrong. `TransparentBlt` does not help. You are still assuming, that the code in the question is rendering the static control. It isn't, and all the information to deduce that is there.

Comment: And that's why I voted -1 on your answer. I don't know, why someone would up vote it. It doesn't address the question.

Comment: Oh yes, it does! And I have suggested two alternatives actually. Esp the owner-drawn solution is easy to implement. The other one is harder, as one would have to deal with ico and pngs, which the tools hardly support.

Comment: None of your alternative suggestions address the question. The question is simply: *"How do I set a static control's image using a dynamically loaded, transparent bitmap?"* Your *"either"* suggestion is **exactly**, what the OP is doing (please, please please please do read the code, and comprehend). And dealing with ICO's is a simple call to `LoadIcon`, and passing the returned handle to the `STM_SETIMAGE` message. Using a PNG ICO does not make matters any more complicated. It is the same code.

Comment: No matter how the question is formed, the goal is to paint a bitmap on a static control. Now if it can be done in a different way, this can be helpful too. And I think you have to agree that the paint request isn't the right place to reconstruct the "transparent" bitmap AND resend it to the control - this should have been done somewhere else.
Anyway, I;m going to post some working code here. You could do the same if you want (and also tell us the tools and the procedure you used and how to cope with that RC2175 error - "not in 3.00 format").