# C++ MFC - Draw an image including transparency in Dialog

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to make Dialog transparent in C++ MFC and draw an image including transparency in Dialog.

First, the code that made the background transparent.

```
cb.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 128, 0));
hbr = (HBRUSH) cb;
```

```
LONG lStyle = ::GetWindowLong(GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_EXSTYLE);
    lStyle |= WS_EX_LAYERED;
    ::SetWindowLong(GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_EXSTYLE, lStyle);
    SetLayeredWindowAttributes(RGB(0, 128, 0), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

Next is the code to draw an image with transparency in Dialog.

```
IStream* pStream = NULL;
HRESULT hr = SHCreateStreamOnFile(L"MY_IMAGE.png", STGM_READ | STGM_SHARE_DENY_WRITE, &pStream);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        CImage image;
        image.Load(pStream);

        image.Save(L"test.png"); // Correct Image

        HBITMAP hBitmap;
        hBitmap = image.Detach();

        BITMAP bmp;
        GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bmp), &bmp);

        int width = bmp.bmWidth;
        int height = bmp.bmHeight;

        CDC* pDC = GetDC();

        CDC hDCMem;
        hDCMem.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
        HBITMAP hBmpOld = (HBITMAP)hDCMem.SelectObject(hBitmap);

        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(rect);

        int imageWidth = bmp.bmWidth;
        int imageHeight = bmp.bmHeight;

        int screenWidth = rect.Width();
        int screenHeight = rect.Height();

        for (int i = 0; i < screenWidth; i += imageWidth) {
            for (int j = 0; j < screenHeight; j += imageHeight) {
                pDC->BitBlt(i, j, bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight, &hDCMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
            }
        }

        hDCMem.SelectObject(hBmpOld);
        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        DeleteObject(image);
        DeleteDC(hDCMem);

    }
```

The result is an image with no transparency displayed on the screen.

Any advice on how to get it on the screen while maintaining transparency?

That's what I've already.

Comment: Don't know much about transparent and layered windows, but as far as transparent drawing is concerned, `BitBlt()` does not perform transparent blitting. Try the `TransparentBlt()` function for one-color transparency, and the `AlphaBlend()` one for alpha-transparency blitting. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406676/settings-transparency-on-bitmap-before-using-stm-setimage/39411834#39411834).

Comment: A few notes about your code, why do you save the "Correct Image"? You don't do anything with it. Also, you should rather process the `WM_PAINT` message, instead of directly drawing (`GetDC()` - no `ReleaseDC()` counterpart btw). And I wouldn't intermix image loading/manipulating with painting/drawing, the former is a "slow" operation, which should be performed only when the image must be changed, while for the latter your app may receive paint requests as a result of various actions or conditions. And finally, you should release any resources, handles, streams etc you allocate, create or open.